# Computing $\int \sin^n ax \, dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, reference-request, hypergeometric-function, proof-explanation

I need to compute the following integral. Looking on an integral table I've found that the closed form of this integral is equal to:

$$
\int \sin^n ax \, dx = -\frac 1 a \cos ax\ _2F_1 \left[ \frac 1 2, \frac{1-n} 2, \frac 3 2 \cos^2 ax \right] \tag{65} 
$$

The problem is that I don't know for what the symbol $_2F_1$ stands for. Moreover, can anybody give me a reference for understanding the derivation above? Maybe a book with a proof with clear definition and passages...

Thanks a lot to anybody who can help!

Edit: I've found that the function above is called hypergeometric function. Anyway, any suggestion for where to find a complete proof for this derivation is greatly appreciated!

Comment: ${}_2F_1$ is the so called hypergeometric function.

Comment: Yep, I've just edited the post because I've found it :P

Comment: This is also what Wolfram Alpha says.  But (for even $n$), although it may be correct for $0 < x < \pi$, it is perhaps not useful.

Answer (score 2):

I tried $a=1, n=2$ ...

[image: I1]

[image: I2]

Actually they do agree (well, differ by a constant) from $0$ to $\pi$.
so perhaps there is some restriction in the formula?

**added**
For odd $n$, that hypergeom is a polynomial.  But not for even $n$.  For fun I expanded the case $n=2$...

$$
-\cos \left( x \right) +\frac{\left( \cos \left( x
 \right)  \right) ^{3}}{6}+\frac{\left( \cos \left( x \right)  \right) ^{
5}}{40}+{\frac { \left( \cos \left( x \right)  \right) ^{7}}{112}}+{\frac {
5\, \left( \cos \left( x \right)  \right) ^{9}}{1152}}+{\frac {7\,
 \left( \cos \left( x \right)  \right) ^{11}}{2816}}
+{\frac {21\, \left( \cos \left( x \right)  \right) ^{13}}{13312}}+{
\frac {11\, \left( \cos \left( x \right)  \right) ^{15}}{10240}}+{
\frac {429\, \left( \cos \left( x \right)  \right) ^{17}}{557056}}+{
\frac {715\, \left( \cos \left( x \right)  \right) ^{19}}{1245184}}+{
\frac {2431\, \left( \cos \left( x \right)  \right) ^{21}}{5505024}}+{
\frac {4199\, \left( \cos \left( x \right)  \right) ^{23}}{12058624}}+
{\frac {29393\, \left( \cos \left( x \right)  \right) ^{25}}{104857600
}}+{\frac {52003\, \left( \cos \left( x \right)  \right) ^{27}}{
226492416}}+{\frac {185725\, \left( \cos \left( x \right)  \right) ^{
29}}{973078528}}+{\frac {334305\, \left( \cos \left( x \right) 
 \right) ^{31}}{2080374784}}+{\frac {3231615\, \left( \cos \left( x
 \right)  \right) ^{33}}{23622320128}}+{\frac {3535767\, \left( \cos
 \left( x \right)  \right) ^{35}}{30064771072}}+{\frac {64822395\,
 \left( \cos \left( x \right)  \right) ^{37}}{635655159808}}+{\frac {
39803225\, \left( \cos \left( x \right)  \right) ^{39}}{446676598784}}
+{\frac {883631595\, \left( \cos \left( x \right)  \right) ^{41}}{
11269994184704}}+{\frac {1641030105\, \left( \cos \left( x \right) 
 \right) ^{43}}{23639499997184}}+{\frac {407771117\, \left( \cos
 \left( x \right)  \right) ^{45}}{6597069766656}}+{\frac {11435320455
\, \left( \cos \left( x \right)  \right) ^{47}}{206708186021888}}+{
\frac {171529806825\, \left( \cos \left( x \right)  \right) ^{49}}{
3448068464705536}}+\dots
$$